# How can i store data in an automatically created variable inside a for-loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, variables

I am messing around a bit with tkinter in python. I am using images for my buttons and want to load them. There's a lot of buttons in my gui, so i thought maybe there's a way to load them and store them in variable generated inside a for loop.

**This is my code:**

```
list1 = ['apple', 'peach', 'orange']
path = 'GUI/Buttons'

def initButtons(partlist : list, path : str):
    buttonsToLoad = ['ButtonActive1.png', 'ButtonInactive1.png', 'ButtonClicked1.png']
    for x in partlist:
        button + [str(x)] + '0' = Image.open(f'{path}/{x}/{buttonsToLoad[0]}')
        button + [str(x)] + '1' = Image.open(f'{path}/{x}/{buttonsToLoad[1]}')
        button + [str(x)] + '2' = Image.open(f'{path}/{x}/{buttonsToLoad[2]}') 

initButtons(list1, path)
```

But this doesn't work! I'm a beginner to python, so maybe there's a much simpler way that I don't know! It's a weird question, i know, but i hope someone understands and can probably help me out!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You cannot really generate variables with different names in a for-loop AFAIK. But you can store the separate buttons in a list, and access them whenever required. Or alternatively you can store them in a dict where the keys are the required "variable names", and the values are the buttons. This solution might require you to save the image with `list(img.get_data())` or something alike, instead of the raw file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not name a different variable at each loop iteration, but you can store them in a `dict {}`:

```
button = {}
def initButtons(partlist : list, path : str):
    buttonsToLoad = ['ButtonActive1.png', 'ButtonInactive1.png', 'ButtonClicked1.png']
    for x in partlist:
        button[str(x) + '0'] = Image.open(f'{path}/{x}/{buttonsToLoad[0]}')
        button[str(x) + '1'] = Image.open(f'{path}/{x}/{buttonsToLoad[1]}')
        button[str(x) + '2'] = Image.open(f'{path}/{x}/{buttonsToLoad[2]}')
```

Then you can access your Image simply by searching its name in the dict's keys:

```
image = button['apple0']  # if its name is 'apple' + '0'
```

Comment: Thanks man! I think this method is much better then mine.